# JBOSS 7.1.1 ear file - update config files inside ear depending on server

Tags: deployment, jboss, automation, ear

I have an ear file which contains web.xml, and some other properties files.

I have multiple qa servers.

Whenever I have to deploy ear file to any server I follow bunch of steps where i update the properties files depending upon given server information.

I want to automate this process or minimize the manual intervention.

Are there any best practices ? what is the better way to do this task?

Thanks